# Maximising the features of php and MySQL when used together

Tags: php, mysql

We are stuck with the infamous php and MySQL combination (for various reasons), and are trying to produce applications which follow best-practice as much as possible.

Unfortunately, despite trying to adhere to [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles, we have noticed there are limitations with MySQL which mean we end up using php for some of the RDBMS functions (for example, MySQL doesn't support CHECK so we have to do validation with php) and at the same time, we have shortcomings with php which mean we use MySQL to do things which aren't feasible in php (strict datatypes, hierarchical data structures, relationships, etc). As a result, despite trying to keep the code clean and loosely-coupled, the foibles of php + MySQL inevitably mean that SQL creeps into the php code in a tightly-coupled manner.

Does anyone have any examples of how to overcome limitations you have come across, or examples of other applications that mix the two up in a similar way?

Comment: Seems like you're using the wrong tools for the job if you've got all these caveats.

Comment: _What_? PHP may not have strict typing (although it can do some basic checks at runtime by using type-hinting), but that doesn't mean you can't do type checking by any means. Similarly, your database should be a _database_. It should house data and you shouldn't rely on it for things that your application should do. Maybe we'd be able to help if you showed us some code.

Comment: I concur with @ColinMorelli. I'm no fan of PHP+MySQL at all, but the limitations you are citing on each side seem a bit strange. Validation is always multi-layered (`CHECK` is not enough), hierarchical data and the type system in MySQL are both quite awful, etc. Some code would be good, otherwise this question is just too broad for SO.

Comment: It is not really clear why not having CHECK in a database or loose datatypes in PHP is stopping you from adhering to SOLID principles. You might try phrasing the question with specific examples where you are having design/architectural challenges.

Comment: this sounds like you don't have a datamapper in between. the program itself doesn't need to know it's working with a database [http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)

Comment: Castis - we're stuck with php + MySQL! Colin, Francis, true a database is a database, but MySQL also purports to be a relational database, so my question is where do you draw the line - what should the application do if the database can do it better - i.e. relational structures? I've seen frameworks that try to replicate a relational structure with ORM (compound keys, TRIGGERs) but fail horribly. Possibly too broad for SO after all?

Comment: Just because frameworks try to do something doesn't mean it's a good idea. Indeed, often it's the complete opposite

Comment: @Dave, hence the question - does anyone have any examples of something that _does_ do it well? Doctrine, for example doesn't do the above very well.

Comment: Honestly I'm not seeing the issue here. Data validation (including type checking) is application logic, it should be in the application. The database should do nothing but store data. Nothing you have mentioned above is anything that PHP is incapable of in any way.

Comment: @DaveRandom - I disagree a '_database should do nothing but store data_'. I suggested in the question that native RDBMS features should be preferred over non-optimal php constructs; TRANSACTIONs, CHECKs, TRIGGERs, etc

Comment: I'm really not sure how transactions enter into it, but `CHECK` and triggers are both offloading business logic to the database, making your application more opaque and coupling it more tightly to a specific RDBMS. Neither of those two things are impossible (or even difficult) with PHP, and would make your application much more transparent (i.e. you only have to look in one place for the logic) and more portable and platform agnostic.

Comment: Not a good sort of question for SO.

Comment: Indeed, it does seem to be tending towards NC, looking at the debate - albeit interesting and civil - that has resulted from it.

Comment: @Dave, this is exactly the type of business logic that RDBMS's were designed to address. The question wasn't supposed to be a debate on "whether php should be used to perform RDBMS functions", but seeing as that is what has happened, I'll concede that SO isn't the best place for this type of question! Where should it move to?

Comment: @boatingcow *Maybe* programmers.SE but I'm not totally certain about that

Comment: I've found an article linked from another post which neatly covers why ORMs can be bad: http://seldo.com/weblog/2011/08/11/orm_is_an_antipattern